# Selective Serialization to CSV, Java

Tags: java, csv, opencsv, supercsv

I am using jsefa library to selectively deserialize a csv for eg. maping only header no. 1,3,5 to my object, this works fine.

Now I want to do the opposite of it selectively serialize my object to header postion 1,3,5 and rest positions should get separated by semicolon (;) automatically.
So the output would look something like this:

```
Header1;Header2;Header3;Header4;Header5;Header6;Header7
bla1;;bla3;;bla5
```

Can anybody suggest, how can this be done with jsefa or with any other library.

Comment: It is unclear what and how you tried. And how opencsv and supercsv are tried by you.

Comment: @RobAu Hi I have't tried opencsv or supercsv, I added these tags so guys who have used these libraries can give some advise. I have only tried jsefa. Let me try to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly achievable with Super CSV. Just supply a `null` entry in the `nameMapping` array to always write a blank column.

```
private static void writePartial() throws IOException {
    Person person1 = new Person("John", "K", "Smith");
    Person person2 = new Person("Sally", "T", "Brown");

    CsvPreference csvPrefs = new CsvPreference.Builder('"', ';', "\n").build();
    String[] nameMapping = new String[] { "firstName", null, "lastName" };

    try (ICsvBeanWriter writer = new CsvBeanWriter(new FileWriter("output.csv"), csvPrefs)) {
        writer.writeHeader("firstName", "middleName", "lastName");
        for( Person p : Arrays.asList(person1, person2) ) {
            writer.write(p, nameMapping);
        }
    }
}
```

You should get the following output:

```
firstName;middleName;lastName
John;;Smith
Sally;;Brown
```

That's probably the easiest solution, but if you're after something more flexible (you might want to validate the field value, but never write it for example), then you can create a custom cell processor to ensure the field is never written.
Just define a cell processor that always ignores the value in the bean:

```
public class Ignore extends CellProcessorAdaptor {

    @Override
    public Object execute(Object value, CsvContext context) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

And then use it:

```
private static void writePartial() throws IOException {
    Person person1 = new Person("John", "K", "Smith");
    Person person2 = new Person("Sally", "T", "Brown");

    CsvPreference csvPrefs = new CsvPreference.Builder('"', ';', "\n").build();
    String[] nameMapping = new String[] { "firstName", "middleName", "lastName" };
    CellProcessor[] processors = new CellProcessor[] { new Optional(), new Ignore(), new Optional() };

    try (ICsvBeanWriter writer = new CsvBeanWriter(new FileWriter("output.csv"), csvPrefs)) {
        writer.writeHeader(nameMapping);
        for( Person p : Arrays.asList(person1, person2) ) {
            writer.write(p, nameMapping, processors);
        }
    }
}
```

So you could chain it together `new NotNull(new Ignore())` to validate that the bean's `middleName` field always has a value, but to never write it. It also means if you change your mind later on and want to write the value, you can replace the `Ignore()` processor with `Optional()` (or `NotNull()`, or whatever you like) and see that it should then write the middle name field, instead of ignoring it.

Comment: This certainly works but how can the same be achived with jsefa?

Answer (score 0):

Just use [uniVocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) as it is MUCH simpler and faster than any other CSV parsing library for Java:

To read:

```
CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
settings.selectIndexes(1, 3, 5);

CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);
List<String[]> parsedRows = parser.parseAll(yourJavaIoReader);
```

To write:

```
CsvWriterSettings settings = new CsvWriterSettings();
settings.selectIndexes(1, 3, 5);

CsvWriter writer = new CsvWriter(outputWriter, settings);
writer.writeAllRowsAndClose(buildMyListOfRowsWith3Elements());
```

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license).